# How to parse the xml with lot of data in small amount of time

Tags: iphone

i am developing one application.In that i parsed the one xml file.That contain the 500 questions and each question have 4 different answers.If i parse that data then it will take lot of time.FIrst i created one class with that question attributes like question content,question type,answers,correct answer likie that.And i created one object for that class and every time parse that file and saved each question information.For this it kwill take lot of time.But i need to get the questions information very fastly.Please tell me is there any other way to get the questions at a time fastly with less time or individual question every time.

Comment: Why don't you parse the whole file and store all the question object in an array and then extract the question from that array?

Comment: I did the same thing.But it will take lot of time for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

- Use SAX parsers. NSXMLParser is a SAX parser

> A SAX parser only needs to report each parsing event as it happens.So it is Faster than DOM.

- If you think parsing freezes your UI. Put it in a back ground thread. `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`
- Do not parse xml every time. Cache the question objects.

Comment: But when i parse all questions ata time it will take lot of time.